# How to open a Python Script in IDLE from a Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

So I've been finding a few answers but none of them do the trick. I'd like to open a file (script.py) in IDLE using a python script (openscript.py). It seems os.system or subprocess.Popen should do the trick but I can't seem to find the correct link to open in IDLE.

```
import os
def openFile():
    filename = "script.py"
    os.system("C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\Lib\\idlelib\\idle.pyw " + filename)

openFile()
```

Comment: What's the issue ? Does Idle open at all or is just the 'script' not shown in Idle ?

Comment: `C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\idlelib>idle.bat C:\Users\xyz\py\filename.py`

Comment: Stylistic suggestion: consider `r' ... '` so you don't have to escape all those backslashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.pyw` is Windows-only, you must be running on Windows.  When asking a question, always give the error message, as it likely has the answer.  On Win10, your code results in a Windows error box saying that there is no app associated with that file and a suggestion to install one if needed.  Replacing `os.system` with `subprocess.run` gives the error `OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`.  So replace `idle.pyw` with the application that will run IDLE.  The following (saved as tem3.py) works for me when run either from an IDLE editor or Command Prompt.

```
import subprocess as sub
def openFile():
    filename = "f:/Python/a/tem3.py"
    sub.run(r"C:\Programs\Python39\pythonw.exe -m idlelib " + filename)

openFile()
```

Comment: Perfect thank you very much! -m idlelib at the end of the link to python did the trick!

Comment: Just as an addition: using subprocess.Popen makes the script you're executing continue. Using subprocess.run stops your script untill you close IDLE.

Comment: Right.  Depends on what one wants.  IDLE itself uses .Popen to start the subprocess that executes user code.